# Is it acceptable in mathematical saying that the E-step is equal to posterior probability

Tags: mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I am studying EM-algorithm for mixture data. I read that some authors said that, the E-step is equivalent to the calculation of the posterior probability (I think this come from Bayesian rule). So, my question is, is it acceptable to says that the E-step is the same as or can be interpreted as a posterior probability? I meant will I be wrong if I said that the E-step can be viewed as a posterior probability that the point $s$ belongs to the $k^{th}$ component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed *incorrect* in that the EM algorithm usually operates outside the Bayesian paradigm and hence *posterior probabilities* are not defined there. What is correct is that the E step for mixtures is equivalent to computing the *conditional probability* of an allocation of observation $i$ to component $j$:
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_j(Z_i)|X_i=x_i,\theta]=\mathbb{P}(Z_i=j|X_i=x_i,\theta)=\dfrac{p_j f(x_i|\theta_j)}{\sum_\nu p_\nu f(x_i|\theta_\nu)}$$
This probability is both conditional on $X_i=x_i$ and on the value of the parameter $\theta$. The posterior probability that $Z_i=j$ would be conditional on the sample $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ only, integrating $\theta$ out.